# "get_template_part" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So, I have following javascript to call a php file to a div when an `id="rhp_id"` is clicked into another div with `id="rhp_front_rhp_id"` (Wordpress).

```
jQuery('#rhp_id').click( function() {   
    get_template_part('page-parts/01_house_rhp_id.php', function(data) {        
        jQuery('#rhp_front_rhp_id').html(data);
        });                 
});
```

I am getting an error saying that `get_template_part is not defined`. 
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks0n

Comment: Is `get_template_part` a wordpress (PHP) function? You are aware, that you can not call PHP function from within an AJAX-call?